# Oracle execution plan changing

Tags: database, oracle

I have a query:

```
             SELECT COUNT(1)
             FROM registration r,
                  proxy p
             WHERE r.participant_code = p.participant_code
               AND r.proxy_type = p.proxy_type
               AND r.proxy_value = p.proxy_value
               AND r.proxy_sequence= p.proxy_sequence
```

All four fields used in join conditions for table 'proxy' are in 'proxy' primary key. Execution plan of the query has been using primary key to make a scan, but since one moment it suddenly changed index scan on full table scan.

After that query was changed a little(joins 'r.proxy_value = p.proxy_value' and 'r.proxy_type = p.proxy_type' where swapped):

```
             SELECT COUNT(1)
             FROM registration r,
                  proxy p
             WHERE r.participant_code = p.participant_code
               AND r.proxy_value = p.proxy_value                   
               AND r.proxy_type = p.proxy_type
               AND r.proxy_sequence= p.proxy_sequence
```

Actually both queries are equivalent. However after this change execution plan of the second query starts using index scan instead of full scan.

Now I have a very specific question:

Will Oracle recompile the second query and will it lead to query execution plan changing?

Comment: The two queries are _apparently_ equivalent/identical except for the order of the conditions within the `WHERE` clause. Though intuitively one may think they are the same, I would make them both identical and re-test (yes, I agree with you that this seams to be a very amateur-like comment, but I was surprised too many times in my life with this type of things).

Comment: You know actually I've tested this scenario(yes behavior has been changed, also please note it's very hard to re-test because I don't have control over Oracle execution plan management mechanism), what I need is detailed explanation of how Oracle treats this situation. Any references on Oracle documentation will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. Did you make both select identical (by changing the order of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause)? If yes, did you observe different execution plans for them?

Comment: First step: on clean database I insert some test data execute both queries, both queries are identical. Second step: on clean database I execute from java application process that makes bulk inserts ans selects. At a point of time I realize that process became too slow. I check excecution plan using dbms tool and find that the query makes full scan instead of index. I replace the query as mentioned above and after that it starts using index(note I don't clean database and it already has approximately 1 million of records)

Comment: When you explain plan for both, does Oracle keep generating different plans or you observe this situation only in first execution and later obtain same plan for both queries? If second is your case I would say first was generated with full scan because there was no stats for table.

Comment: @Kacper, he wrote that the JAVA performs both bulk inserts and selects, meaning that statistics should build up from the beginning.

Comment: @FDavidov Exactly. At the beginning both queries use index scan and only some time when bulk process is running I observe this change in execution plan.

Comment: Do you by chance have some implicit _conversion_ (like case insensitive for text fields)?

Comment: No conversion. I intentionally didn't provide more details on that, I want to narrow this question down to a question what are the conditions when Oracle changes execution plans. I tried to find any information about in Oracle documentation but didn't succeed. May be you could point me on the appropriate source.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add both execution plans. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also which exact Oracle version are you using? Newer versions can change the plan even for identical queries if the feedback from a first run showed that it might not have been an ideal plan.

Comment: My version is 12.1.0.2.0, execution plans of both queries in the beginning are absolutely identical, another plans during the bulk I can't provide because it takes too much time to reproduce. However I'm not interesting in the reason why does this happens, only in theoretical question posted above: must execution plan for the queries above be the same or not

Answer (score 1):

Oracle now uses the cost-based optimizer (CBO) by default, versus the former rule-based optimizer which was more predictable but way less capable in data warehouse scenarios.

In general, CBO introduced "plan stability" issues, whereas the RBO's plans always remained the same.

Using the CBO means that execution plans can and will be changing on their own, based on changes in the statistics and/or dynamic sampling data. There are actually tools that allow to monitor the plan switch history (e.g. lab128).

Another point I noticed when looking at your query: there are no filters, so depending an what your actual primary keys are, there might be little usage for an index scan.

Comment: @mvb13 - this is my guess as well, what has changed is the underlying data. Are you able to generate explain plans based on exactly the same data at some point in time, and compare those? (Keep in mind, if you run the two queries in two different sessions, even at the exact same time, their data may still be different if one or both of the sessions has/have uncommitted transactions).